# changing the button image from another .m file

Tags: ios, global-variables, segue

I am trying to make a planning poker app.

I have the following set up

1. ViewController: where the user selects the cards, has 12 buttons.
2. a viewcontroller on storyboard: has a big button with the back side of the card
3. CardViewController: has a button view that should display the selected card dynamically.

Now i am having trouble displaying the right card in CardViewController. I've tried the prepareforsegue function but it's just not working. I also tried using a global variable but my objc skills aren't strong enough.

Can someone help or suggest what i can do? Thanks!

**Code**:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"display"]) {

    // Get destination view
    CardViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Get button tag
    NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    NSLog(@"%d", tagIndex);
    // Set the selected button in the new view
    [vc setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
}
}
```

Comment: prepareforsegue is the best solution, what's not working about it? how do you try to use it (some code if possible)

Comment: hi, i've added the code above. it compiles but it crashes when i choose a card number in the first view, resulting in a sigabrt error.

Comment: post your relevant error code

Comment: how/where do you call prepareForSegue

Comment: int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: my prepareforsegue function is in the viewcontroller.m file

Answer (score 0):

Well now in your `CardViewController` class you have a method called `setSelectedButton` you should keep your index to use after that when the view finish loading:

```
- (void) setSelectedButton:(NSInteger) tagIndex
{
  self.selectedTagIndex = tagIndex;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // here use self.selectedTagIndex to do the modifications on the view
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is selectedTagIndex?

Comment: its a property that you should declare in your .h file `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedTagIndex;`

Comment: sorry, prepareforsegue

Comment: Yes, I thought you can see the NSLog showing the value of tagIndex!!

Comment: i cant, it does crashes even before it can even show. i will look into my code again. thanks for your help!